# What is the correct way to load data from thousands of users without slowing down our vue.js and firebase app?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

We recently launched an application for a company that provides staff for music festivals using vue.js and a firebase realtime database. We have about 2,000 users and currently 8 events that they can apply for. Each user has profiles and admins can manage their events and hires from the app. The app fires up right away, but the data in "getInitialUserState" takes a long time to populate. I'm worried that once we have 5K or 10K users, load time will only get worse.

In our App.vue file:

```
created () {
this.$store.dispatch("getInitialState")
this.$store.dispatch("getInitialEventsState")
}
```

Then in Users.vue:

```
created () {
  this.$store.dispatch("getInitialUserState")
}
```

In our store:

```
getInitialState({ commit }) {
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    console.log(user);
    const db = firebase.database();
    db.ref('users/').child(user.uid).on('value', (snap)=>{
      let u = snap.val();
      u.id = user.uid
      commit('setUser', u);
    }) 
  })
},
getInitialUserState({commit}, payload){
  const db = firebase.database()
  db.ref("users").once("value", (snap) => {
    let data = []
    for(var key in snap.val()){
      let user = snap.val()[key]
      user.id = key
      data.push(user)
    }
    commit('setUsers', data)
    commit('setUsersMap', snap.val());
  })
},
```

and:

```
getInitialEventsState({ commit }) {
  let db = firebase.database();
  db.ref("/events").on("value", function (snapshot) {
    let data = []
    for (var key in snapshot.val()) {
      let event = snapshot.val()[key];
      if(event.title){
        event.id = key
        data.push(event)            
      }
    }
    commit("setLoadedEvents", data)
    commit("setEventsMap", snapshot.val());
  })
}
```

We've tried adding v-cloak to different elements so don't render without all of the correct data, but that either doesn't work or we are doing it wrong. I've also tried loading data at different lifecycle hooks, but that doesn't make any difference either.

What I want to happen is for my data (as a logged-in user) and for event data to load immediately. Then, EITHER for the "Users" data to only load if the user in a admin (so it won't slow down the experience for regular users), or for Users data to load asynchronously and without interfering with the rest of the app. Currently, while the Users data is loading, the page is effectively frozen and you can't click to go to any other pages.

Firebase should be fast. We are using firebase hosting as well. I'm hoping you guys can at least point us in the right direction.

What is the correct way to load data from thousands of users without slowing down the user experience?

Thanks!

Comment: Pagination? Surely you don't need all 2,000 users loaded all at once?

Comment: The Users layout has a vuetify data table that works great for pagination, searching, and sorting. It's just that initial load from firebase that's killing us.

Comment: Use webworkers to fetch chunks and load them in as they're received. I do this loading in tables with 100k+ records into ag-grid using 500 records per chunk. It works very well.

Comment: Paginate server-side if possible: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#example-server

Comment: Researching web workers, it looks like there are some serious drawbacks with mobile support (they won't work on safari). Am I missing something? [https://forum.vuejs.org/t/would-it-be-possible-to-offload-some-work-e-g-the-render-function-to-a-webworker/8118]